# Override mangento search system to allow random order

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I need to find a way to either add another sort order so that I can sort by random or I need to override the core search system to allow me to achieve the same. (or some combination of the two?)

I know that the magento search files are in app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/ but I am unsure as to which files I need to look at changing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file you are looking for is `app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Layer.php`. The name of the class is `Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer`. Inside it you see the function `prepareProductCollection($collection)`.

I suggest you rewrite this model (see [this](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/how_to_override_magento_model_classes/) or [this](http://www.excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-part10-series-overriding)) and override the aforementioned function and add/implement you sorting logic. An example of overriding this function would be

```
class XXX_XXX_Model_CatalogSearch_Layer extends Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Layer
{
    public function prepareProductCollection($collection)
    {
        parent::prepareProductCollection($collection);
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('some_attribute');
        $collection->setOrder('some_attribute', 'asc');
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

go to file location community\app\code\core\Mage\CatalogSearch\Block\Result.php and find function public function setListOrders() and here you can change to your custom order